# C++/CLI wrapper can't use vector from native C++ dll

Tags: c++, c++-cli, linker-errors

I have a project that goes like this: C++ -> C++/CLI wrapper -> C# app.

I have an **exported** class called `Drawing` in the C++ dll, .h contains a `static std::vector<void*>`, the vector is **defined** in the .cpp file.

The problem is that I'm getting the following errors:

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWI7r.png)

C++'s native dll .lib file is linked to the wrapper, and generally the wrapper works with other stuff, but once I add the std::vector, it starts throwing linker errors.

I tried creating a function in the C++ dll that has `void*` as an argumument and added to the list "internally", but I still got the same errors kind of:

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3PdT.png)

Any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: I suspect problem with the signature. You exported symbol `std::vector<void*>` whereas linker expects `std::vector<void*, ALLOCATOR>`. Maybe a solution would be to wrap a vector into a simpler, non-template structure?

Comment: Standard C++ bug, you declared the static members but did not define them.  Google "c++ static member definition" to find hits, first one is decent.

Comment: @Hans Passant, I have it defined in the .cpp file, as I mentioned.

Comment: @woockashek, how would I wrap the vector into a non-template structure?

Answer (score 0):

Answer extending my comment.
You could try to wrap the `std::vector<void*>` into simpler structure with functionalities you really need like following:

```
class YourClass
{
private:
    std::vector<void*> _vec;

public:
    // implement functionalities you need
    void add(void* elem)
    {
        _vec.add(elem);
    }
    // etc.
};
```

or by inheritance:

```
class YourClass : public std::vector<void*>
{
public:
    YourClass(int size)
    : std::vector<void*>(size) {}
};
```

Comment: I tried something similair, but since it's not static and I'm exporting the whole class (using declspec(dllexport)), I had to do the following in my wrapper: `Class x = new Class();  x->Add(func.ToPointer();` and that didn't add it, from what I saw, I printed the size of the vector before and after and it added it, but since I'm doing `new Class()`, I couldn't use it in my C++ dll because it was still empty. (or that's what I think is going on).